# how to reduce (or eliminate) mysql "table does not exist" errors when renaming a table to a new version of itself

Tags: mysql

Getting some "myTable does not exist" errors while renaming a table to an updated version of itself. Not sure if I'm doing it right.

I have a web site where users run queries against a table that is replaced once every 5 minutes with an updated copy of itself. The table has 600,000 rows and needs to be built from scratch once every few minutes so that it is internally consistent.

This is how I do the table update:

```
// not shown: bunch of code to build newTable from scratch; takes 90 seconds
// while this is happening users are querying myTable

// Then, on a 5 minute mark, this happens:

START TRANSACTION
RENAME TABLE myTable TO oldTable // fast, like 0.005 seconds
RENAME TABLE newTable TO myTable // fast, like 0.005 seconds
COMMIT

DROP oldTable // a bit slow... like 0.5 to 1.0 seconds
```

I put the DROP outside the transaction because I'm trying to minimize the time when myTable doesn't exist.

During this transition period (which happens every 5 min) I'm getting a 1 to 3 mysql errors "myTable does not exist".

I'm not sure if some users are just starting a query exactly during the time when myTable has been renamed (and therefore does not exist) before newTable has been renamed to myTable? It's a pretty tiny window; I think the transaction takes 0.01 seconds and there are maybe 20-30 users on the site at one time (according to Google Analytics) running queries.

Or maybe there are some longer queries in progress just before I rename myTable to oldTable? Does a query from another thread fail if you take its table away in another thread?

Should I even be using START TRANSACTION / COMMIT for this use case?

All tables are InnoDB. Mysql version is "Ver 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))"

Any suggestions on how I can get rid of the "myTable does not exist" errors while I'm in the middle of renaming the tables once every 5 minutes?

Comment: I think first rename line is repeated by another thread before the next line by another thread. In which case you indeed haven't the table.

Comment: I tried the atomic rename and that solved the issue. Thanks! I also read that RENAME will wait until any queries using the table are finished, so the time for RENAME can be super quick (if no one using table) or slow (if in middle of slow query from another thread).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will work for your use case, but one way you could achieve the same result without rebuilding the table every few minutes would be like this:

- Only use one table, but add a column to it that defines the version number or something similar.
- In your 'rebuild' step, add rows to the table with a new version id.
- While this is happening query the table for the previous version id
- At the 5 minute mark, start querying for the new version id.
- Remove all rows from the table that have the old version id

Comment: I could do that but I'm concerned about performance. The table is read-only during it's 5 min lifespan. While users are querying it, I'm building its replacement with fresher data (which comes from several sources). After 90 seconds of building I have a newer version of the table. 600K rows. I suppose I could insert the 600K rows into the existing table (with version id), and then delete the old 600K rows but I wonder if db performance would be slow during that insert/delete time? Was trying to make the queries super fast, all the time.

Answer (score 0):

> Updated:

> I think using two tables with same structure between which you can switch would solve you problem. Let's say we have TableA and TableB, and currently your application is reading data from tableA. Once you receive a new snapshot and process the data, try inserting it in the non-used table(TableB).

> Once data is inserted, you may switch your reference from tableA to tableB.
> You may perform a *select with limit 1*, to get the timestamp from both tables, to check which onc contains stale data and should be overridden. And same logic can be used to reference the correct table.

**Similar to having two partitions and switching b/w the two OS**

> Same logic can be abstracted in a Stored Procedure, which you can call to insert or fetch data. And the Stored Procedure would decide which table to refer. This would reduce multiple DB calls from the application.

To start with,

> START TRANSACTION won't help as RENAME is a DDL command

And the syntax is incorrect (oldTableName then newTableName):

```
RENAME TABLE oldTable TO newTable;
```

You can use a store procedure, which first checks if table exists before renaming, to avoid errors and silently fail the queries.

```
 DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_RENAME_TABLE(IN newTable VARCHAR(64), IN oldTable VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE 
            table_schema    = DATABASE()     AND
            table_name      = oldTable LIMIT 1)
    THEN
        SET @query = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', oldTable, ' TO ', newTable, ';');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @query; 
        EXECUTE stmt; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
    END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL SP_RENAME_TABLE('new_table_name', 'old_table_name');
```

Comment: And ideally, such operations should not be done when the systems are online. This is a very unusual operation to recreate a table every few minutes.
Can you elaborate the use-case?

Comment: The use case is stock market data; I get stock quotes from one source, and option quotes from another source. They are each snapshots of all quotes at a precise moment in time. I get the data updated every 5min from both sources. Then I build a consolidated table with all quote data, add on some other data from a 3rd source (dividends and earnings dates) and after 90 seconds have one compete, consistent table. Then I want to swap it out for the current table.

Comment: I have updated the answer. A solution that might work, but we need to check the efficiency.